# Creating a multiple field form in one row in Avada Theme

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I’ve got to get the below form code onto a single row like: http://snag.gy/k5yrv.jpg

```
<form method="GET" action="YOUR_JOBS_PAGE_URL">
  <p>
    <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
    <input type="text" id="search_keywords" name="search_keywords" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="keywords">Location</label>
    <input type="text" id="search_location" name="search_location" />
  </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </p>
</form>
```

I’m using Avada Theme Contact Form 7 and I need to create a form with multiple fields in one row will look like this. For example, this uses 3 column sections, one field per column:

```
div class="fusion-one-third one_third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes">Your Name (required) [text* your-name]</div>
<div class="fusion-one-third one_third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes">Your Message [textarea your-message]</div>
<div class="fusion-one-third one_third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes fusion-column-last">[submit "Send"]</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Surely can you not just do:

```
<div class="fusion-one-third one_third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes">[text keywords placeholder "job title, keywords or company name"]</div>
<div class="fusion-one-third one_third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes">[text location placeholder "city, province or region"]</div>
<div class="fusion-one-third one_third fusion-layout-column fusion-spacing-yes fusion-column-last">[submit "Search"]</div>
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question completely?

Comment: So, are you _actually_ using Contact Form 7 for this, or a custom form that you wish to look like Contact Form 7 does in Avada?

Comment: I have Contact Form 7 installed, so I was going to use that. But it doesn't have to be using that. Only thing is I'd like the submit button to take on Avada Theme styling. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help bluewhitew, but I don't think that would work. The full code is below. I missed something out because I don't want a 'Category' field, but I think I left out an important function. As clicking submit should take you to a job list page, with your selection listed.

```
<form method="GET" action="YOUR_JOBS_PAGE_URL">
  <p>
    <label for="keywords">Keywords</label>
    <input type="text" id="search_keywords" name="search_keywords" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="keywords">Location</label>
    <input type="text" id="search_location" name="search_location" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="search_category">Category</label>
    <select id="search_category" name="search_category">
        <?php foreach ( get_job_listing_categories() as $cat ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $cat->term_id ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $cat->name ); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </p>
</form>
```